# Is there a list of my owned psn games?

Tags: psn

I bought some psn games before, some psp and psx games, and one vita game. But I'm not sure which ones since it has been a while and not all of them are stored on my memory card anymore. Does Sony provide a list of owned games somewhere? I'd like to have a list of all the psn games I have bought before, so I can download all of them to my new memory card. (the previous one didn't have enough space available so I deleted games I didn't play anymore)
I know this is a bit off-topic, but I still think the question is relevant to the gaming.SE community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there actually is a list with all contents you have ever "purchased" over PSN (for free content, "purchase" means the first time you downloaded it). That list includes content from the PS3 or PS Vita (possibly also PSP), regardless of which system you are currently using to view the list.
Unfortunately, the list isn't very user-friendly; the more you purchased, the more difficult it is to find what you're looking for. It is sorted by date of purchase and it is currently not possible to change the sorting order.

Here's how to view the list (I have German localization, so the options' names are likely not accurate):

#### PS3:

Launch the store app, then go down to the third-to-last option, called *Show downloads*.

#### PS Vita:

Launch the store app, then touch the `...` button on the bottom right corner of the screen; touch the second option from the top, called *Download List*.

#### PSP:

(I do not own a PSP, so feel free to edit this point)

---

Any and all content featured on that list may be downloaded again for free. The only limitation is that you can't download PS3 content to the PS Vita (possibly also the PSP), and that PSP content can only be downloaded onto a PS Vita, if that content is also available in the PS Vita store (you can still download the content over a PS3 and transfer it to the Vita, although there is no guarantee that the transfer will actually succeed)

Comment: Like @Zorpix's answer, this not only lists games/apps I own but also game demos etc... Still a nice find, since I wouldn't have to start up my pc to see the list.

Comment: @Kevin The methods I mentioned list **all** content you have ever purchased (for free content - including demos - "purchased" means the first time you downloaded it). It won't list demos unless you have downloaded them at least once (perhaps someone else downloaded those while you weren't watching?)

Comment: No I downloaded the demo myself and I'm aware that it's a demo (it's rayman origins btw). It's just confusing, because it only says 'rayman origins' and not that it is 'just' a demo. It would be nice if Sony provided a way to distinguish at a glance.

Comment: @Kevin Ah, I see what you mean. Some demos are labeled as [Demo], some aren't (which is weird and confusing); the PSN store never was very consistent to begin with (you'd see demos sometimes under `Extras`, sometimes under `Games`, sometimes under both; not to mention some demos being featured under neither, making it necessary to use the `Search` feature to actually find them, if they exist). Sony really messed up with their store...

Comment: Marking as answered, I don't think there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you go into the PS store, then go to account -> available downloads. It will list everything you've bought/downloaded previously and have the option to download them again if they aren't already saved to your system.

Comment: It also lists games/apps I don't own though, but it seems this is as close as it gets. Thank you.

Comment: no problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way,

go to account management on SEN, then up to the right of screen, there is a tab named "media", there you can filter all the content from your account, including games.

Answer (score 0):

I use this app 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.lwentunrini.sonymedialist

With this I can see all my games, videos, musics, etc...